# Vector processor operates on all its elements at the same time?

Tags: vectorization

Vector processor operates on all vectors elements at the same time? 
If yes dont we require as many threads as the no. of elements in the vector (VLEN)?

And if my understanding is wrong, then if this processor works on each data point consecutively, then is this not same as scalar processor ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer with the same level of specificity as your question, then yes - vectorization, in the [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) sense, operates on all vector elements at the same time.

> If yes dont we require as many threads as the no. of elements in the
>   vector (VLEN)?

Why would we? The operation happens within the same processing thread, leveraging the processor's multiple registers to operate concurrently.

Comment: would not this be Array Processor then?